# Qt + .NET - Сокеты

Tags: сервер, .net, сокет, клиент-сервер, qt

Есть сервер на Qt, кроме него есть клиент на .NET
Сам клиент к серверу подключается, но информацию передать не могу. В чем может быть дело? Куда смотреть, где искать?
Если клиент пишу на Qt - то все работает верно.
Хм.. ну ладно, вот код, хотя особого смысла не вижу. Все стандартно.

```
void Server::slotReadClient()
{
    QTcpSocket* pClientSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QDataStream in(pClientSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_2); //Править надо тут похоже, но не факт
    for (;;) {
        if (!m_nNextBlockSize) {
            if ((quint16)pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) {
                break;
            }
            in >> m_nNextBlockSize;
        }

        if (pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_nNextBlockSize) {
            break;
        }

        QString str;
        in >> str;

        QString strMessage = "Клиент(" + pClientSocket->peerAddress().toString() + ":" + QString::number(pClientSocket->peerPort()) + "): " + str;
        sendToConsole(strMessage);

        m_nNextBlockSize = 0;

        sendToClient(pClientSocket, "Server Response: Received \"" + str + "\"");
    }
```

}

Это как я получаю инфу на сервере, лично я считаю что я намудрил с QDataStream, т.к. в клиенте он тоже используется, если я конечно его пишу на Qt. А вот если .net - я не могу понять в чем дело и как там писать правильно что бы сервер понял клиента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Visteras](/users/16403/visteras)](/users/16403/visteras), платформа .NET знать не знает о типе QString, т.к. это сложный класс, имеет определенную структуру и методы, о которых известно только самому Qt, следовательно, нужно передавать не экземпляр класса QString, а байты "чистых данных" без обвязок или QByteArray (однако, можно посылать и принимать простые типы, как quint16, они имеют линейную структуру и занимают фиксированное количество байт в памяти, в данном случае 2 байта, то есть

```
in >> m_nNextBlockSize;
```

считывает ровно 2 байта и интерпретирует как quint16). В этом куске кода мы с помощью readRawData() экземпляра класса QDataStream читаем последовательность байт длинной m_nNextBlockSize, и после интерпретируем их как QString:

```
void Server::slotReadClient()
{
  QTcpSocket* pClientSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
  QDataStream in(pClientSocket);
  in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_2); //не факт

  QByteArray receivedRawString;

  for (;;) {
    if (!m_nNextBlockSize) {
      if ((quint16)pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) {
        break;
      }
      in >> m_nNextBlockSize;
    }

    if (pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_nNextBlockSize) {
      break;
    }

    receivedRawString.resize(m_nNextBlockSize);
    in.readRawBytes(&receivedRawString, m_nNextBlockSize);
    QString str(receivedRawString);

    QString strMessage = "Клиент(" + pClientSocket->peerAddress().toString() + ":" + QString::number(pClientSocket->peerPort()) + "): " + str;
    sendToConsole(strMessage);

    m_nNextBlockSize = 0;

    sendToClient(pClientSocket, "Server Response: Received \"" + str + "\"");
    }
}
```