# TCP C# -> Qt проблема с чтением

Tags: c#, .net, qt, qt5, mono

Есть простой TCP-сервер на *Qt* и клиент на *C#*.
На клиенте отправляю через `NetworkStream`:

```
byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)(command.Length + 4));
stream.Write(length, 0, length.Length);
```

Получаю:

```
QByteArray data = m_socket->readAll();
QDataStream ss(data);
qDebug() << data;
qDebug() << data.size();
qDebug() << data.toInt();
```

Выхлоп:

> "\x06\x00\x00\x00"
>
> 4
>
> 0

Почему я не могу в итоге получить адекватный набор байтов?

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/281172/qt-net-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B?rq=1

Comment: Мстислав Павлов, я работаю с цифрами int в байты и потом обратно, кодировкой чего?

Comment: Смотрел, но в моем случае я просто пытаюсь передать 16 битное число, но получить его на сервере я не могу.

Comment: А что вы реально посылаете? Какие байты?

Comment: Приложу скрин для наглядности [Скрин](http://li.avenger-web.ru/photo.png)

Comment: @avengerweb: Нет, это же на стороне сервера! А какие конкретно _байты_ посылает клиент?

Comment: Кстати, непонятно, почему `readAll()` должно вернуть ровно те байты, которые принадлежат числу.

Comment: @avengerweb: Если вы реально отправляете число 6, то приходящие данные как раз в порядке. А вот `QDataStream` делает, судя по всему, что-то не то.

Comment: QDataStream в данном случае не делает ничего, оно там есть до лучших времен.

Comment: http://li.avenger-web.ru/photo-2.png

Comment: @avengerweb: Но всё же! Клиент посылает число 6? Если да, то проблема в коде сервера, данные пришли правильно.

Comment: Сервер просто как пробка. В том то и проблема, что с сервером на QT, оно работает, а вот с .net нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны посылать данные в network order'е, и принимать в нём же.

На стороне клиента это выглядит так:

```
byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)(command.Length + 4));
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(length);
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а причем тут _network order_? На обоих концах провода - массивы байт, сформированные с использованием endian по-умолчанию. В процессе формирования ни один массив не знает, что он имеет отношение к сети и что он содержит числа `int`. Или вы просто используете это название как синоним big-endian?

Comment: @DmitryD.: Это сеть. На разных хостах имеют право быть разные порядки байт. В сети данные принято передавать в network order'е, который [совпадает с big endian](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13514614/276994).

Comment: Понимаю. Простите, что пристаю, но на самом первом скрине видно, что хост один (поищите глазами 127.0.0.1). Тем не менее, порядок байт разный. ;)

Comment: @DmitryD.: Хе, а это и правда интересно :) С другой стороны, `m_socket->readAll();` вполне может по личной инициативе предполагать сетевой порядок байт (а какой ещё?) и конвертировать в порядок байт хоста.

Comment: Да просто тут дело не в разной архитектуре процессоров или ОС, а в различиях компиляторов и/или конфигурации проектов на шарпе и на плюсах, имхо. Насчет `m_socket->readAll()` это вы немного погорячились, как мне кажется. Откуда ему знать, что в буфере 1 число типа `int`, а не, например, 2 `short` или 4 `byte`?

Comment: @DmitryD.: А это легко проверить: послать два байта **один за одним** и глянуть, что и в каком порядке пришло.

Comment: `m_socket->readAll()` и правда порядок байт не меняет. А вот методы, которые преобразуют эти байты в число, наверняка про сетевой порядок байт в курсе.

Comment: Спасибо, да, в итоге получилось получить желаемую шестерку.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я помню, метод `QByteArray.toInt` преобразует **строку** в целое число. На это указывает и [документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toInt).

Попробуйте следующий подход:

```
QDataStream ss(data);
int commandLength;
ss >> commandLength;
```

---

Еще в Qt-шной программе запросто может быть другой порядок байтов (BigEndian).
В этом случае следует предварительно сделать реверс:

```
std::reverse(ss.constBegin(), ss.constEnd());
```

Или на клиенте:

```
Array.Reverse(length);
```

Comment: Я не имею чистых байтов чтобы считать число, в этом то вся и проблема, ваш способ тоже ничего не дает, да и читалось все изначально для потока, но я как можно больше упростил прежде чем разместить этот вопрос здесь.

Comment: @avengerweb Что такое _чистый_ байт? Мой подход должен работать. Он, в отличие от `QByteArray.toInt`, тупо перегоняет 4 байта из потока в `int`, не пытаясь распарсить. Покажите скрин, что происходит, когда работает "мой" код.

Comment: http://li.avenger-web.ru/photo-3.png

Comment: @avengerweb Всё ясно. У вас порядок байтов "не тот". В Qt-шной программе, видимо, используется BigEndian. Попробуйте предварительно обратить массив байтов. Добавлю в ответ...